# When using Java's FileLock, is it ok to let close() to automatically do a lock.release()?

Tags: java, nio, filelock

As most should know `close()` also closes any streams uses.

This allows the follow code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(...)));
...
br.close();
```

This is nice, since we don't need a reference to `FileInputStream` and remember to close it.

But does it also work for `FileLock`s?

```
final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("buffer.txt"));
final FileChannel c = fis.getChannel();
final FileLock lock = c.lock(0L, Long.MAX_VALUE, true);
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

try {
    while(br.ready()) {
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

I've tried this code and the lock is correctly released when `br.close()` is called, but is is safe to do so?  The [Closeable JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close()) says, *"Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it."*  Am I safe to assume that I am using `close()` as specified to `release()` the lock?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html):

> It remains valid until the lock is
>   released by invoking the release
>   method, by closing the channel that
>   was used to acquire it, or by the
>   termination of the Java virtual
>   machine, whichever comes first.

And here are the contents of `FileInputStream.close()`

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (channel != null)
        channel.close();
    close0();
}
```

It looks like `close` on the stream closes the channel which releases the lock.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Locks depend on a file descriptor. When there is no file descriptor representing a file in a process, there wouldn't be a lock associated with it.